# Simple lookup and update records function...that I can't make work

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

This will be light work for someone who knows what they're doing but I'm a Javascript novice and just need a little help. Just trying to understand better a few things I've 'learned' from freecodecamp...

I have two functions, 1 of them is a lookup function (which I have working) and the other is a function which theoretically should allow me to update the `number` value within a contacts list when a person's `number`'s value is `unknown`.

So if a `name` is passed into the function and matches with the `firstName` in the contacts, the `number` that is passed in will set the new value.

Here is my code,

```js
//Setup
//Setup
var contacts = [{
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) { // 1
        if (contacts[i].firstName === name) { // 2
            if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) { // 3
                return contacts[i][prop];
            } else {
                return "No such property";
            }
        }
    }
    return "No such contact";
};

function updateRecords(name, num) {
    if (contacts["firstName"] === name && contacts["number"] === "unknown") {
        contacts["number"] = num;
    }
    return contacts;
};
// Change these values to test your function
console.log(updateRecords("Kristian", "123456709"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "lastName"));
```

The update Records function isn't changing the `number` property.
The debug console just shows

```
Array(4) [Object, Object, Object, Object]
Laine
```

If someone can tell me where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate it...
Thankyou!

Comment: since contacts is an array you have to loop it and then search for the name within the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contacts` is not single objects. Its array of objects. And all the properties on each object inside array not on array it self. You you need a loop here. Also you don't need to return `contacts` from function it will automatically update the original `contacts` variable

```
function updateRecords(name, num) {
   for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
      if (contacts[i]["firstName"] === name && contacts[i]["number"] === "unknown") {
         contacts[i]["number"] = num;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much @Maheer! Much appreciated!

Comment: @RuariDouglas Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with answer